# List of compatible or non-compatible video cards for Unity 3d

Tags: 11.04, video

I need to upgrade my video card to make my system compatible with Unity 3d, is there a list of compatible or non-compatible video cards for "natty" and/or "unity3d?" Is there a brand or make I should "steer clear of?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a full, complete list that I am aware of. However Unity hardware requirements are detailed here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/UnityHardwareRequirements